# How do I find a GridView item at button_click?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am using the following code:

```
foreach (GridViewRow dr in gvrejectreq.Rows)
{
    DropDownList ddl=(DropDownList)gvrejectreq.Rows[dr.RowIndex].FindControl("DropDownList1");
    string status = ddl.SelectedValue;
    int userid = gvrejectreq.Rows[dr.RowIndex].
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking...you don't need to loop...

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e){
   if (e.CommandName == "thiscommandname") {
      int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
      GridViewRow selectedRow = ((GridView)e.CommandSource).Rows[index];
      //and then for example...
      string rowText = (LinkButton)selectedRow.Cells[0].Controls[0]).Text;}
}
```